# python: Lark-parser

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, parsing, lark-parser

I use the Lark library to parse boolean expressions like

```
(A=(value1) OR B>(value2)) AND C<=(value3)
```

and I also use it to parse keyless expressions like

```
(A OR B) AND C
```

the parser works correctly until I try to parse a keyless expression containing not only letters and numbers but other characters as well

```
valu* OR text
```

in this case the parser crashes with the exception that it does not recognise the character

Although if you use a key expression, it works correctly

```
A=(valu* OR text) AND B=(value2)
```

**Please tell me where I have a bug in my code and how it can be fixed.**

**Code:**

```
from lark import Lark, Tree, Token

rules = """
?start: expr
?expr: link_or

?link_or: (link_or "or"i)? link_and
?link_and: (link_and "and"i)? ( NAME | cond_eq | cond_gt | cond_ge | cond_lt | cond_le )

?cond_eq: KEY "=" const | "(" expr ")"
?cond_gt: KEY ">" const | "(" expr ")"
?cond_ge: KEY ">=" const | "(" expr ")"
?cond_lt: KEY "<" const | "(" expr ")"
?cond_le: KEY "<=" const | "(" expr ")"

KEY: NAME

?const: INT -> int
      | string_raw -> string

?string_raw: /\((?:[^)(]+|\((?:[^)(]+|\([^)(]*\))*\))*\)/

%import common.CNAME -> NAME
%import common.WS_INLINE
%import common.INT
%ignore WS_INLINE
        """

parser = Lark(rules)

for text in ("key1=(value1*) OR key2=(value2)", "key1 OR key2", "key1* OR key2"):
    print("text:", text)
    try:
        tree = parser.parse(text)
        print("parsed tree:", tree)
    except BaseException as e:
        print("Exception:", e)
    print()
```

**Output**

example #1: `"key1=(value1*) OR key2=(value2)"`: **OK**

```
text: key1=(value1*) OR key2=(value2)
parsed tree: Tree(Token('RULE', 'link_or'), [Tree(Token('RULE', 'cond_eq'), [Token('KEY', 'key1'), Tree('string', [Token('__ANON_2', '(value1*)')])]), Tree(Token('RULE', 'cond_eq'), [Token('KEY', 'key2'), Tree('string', [Token('__ANON_2', '(value2)')])])])
```

example #2: `"key1 OR key2"`: **OK**

```
text: key1 OR key2
parsed tree: Tree(Token('RULE', 'link_or'), [Token('NAME', 'key1'), Token('NAME', 'key2')])
```

example #3: `"key1* OR key2"`: **FAILED**

```
text: key1* OR key2
Exception: No terminal matches '*' in the current parser context, at line 1 col 5

key1* OR key2
    ^
Expected one of: 
    * __ANON_1
    * OR
    * LESSTHAN
    * AND
    * MORETHAN
    * __ANON_0
    * EQUAL
```

example #3 without `try except` block:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\codes\python\test.py", line 34, in <module>
    tree = parser.parse(text)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\lark\lark.py", line 645, in parse
    return self.parser.parse(text, start=start, on_error=on_error)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\lark\parser_frontends.py", line 96, in parse
    return self.parser.parse(stream, chosen_start, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\lark\parsers\earley.py", line 266, in parse
    to_scan = self._parse(lexer, columns, to_scan, start_symbol)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\lark\parsers\xearley.py", line 146, in _parse
    to_scan = scan(i, to_scan)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\lark\parsers\xearley.py", line 119, in scan
    raise UnexpectedCharacters(stream, i, text_line, text_column, {item.expect.name for item in to_scan},
lark.exceptions.UnexpectedCharacters: No terminal matches '*' in the current parser context, at line 1 col 5

key1* OR key2
    ^
Expected one of: 
    * __ANON_1
    * __ANON_0
    * LESSTHAN
    * MORETHAN
    * AND
    * OR
    * EQUAL
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: it would be simpler if you would create `minimal working code` so we could copy and test it.

Comment: @furas - added the info

Comment: Isn't that error message clear? "No terminal matches '*'…" is surely true: `*` is not a valid character for `NAME`.